# Возможно ли в java передать массив через конструктор?

Tags: java, массивы, конструктор, параметры

Формулировка задачи такова:
Создайте структуру с именем student, содержащую поля: фамилия и инициалы, номер группы, успеваемость (массив из пяти элементов). Создать массив из десяти элементов такого типа, упорядочить записи по возрастанию среднего балла. Добавить возможность вывода фамилий и номеров групп студентов, имеющих оценки, равные только 4 или 5.

Вроде как все предельно просто, но не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы объекты создавались со всеми полями?

Как исправить этот код?

```
public class Students {
private String name;
private int numG;
public int[] marks = new int[5];
private double sr;

public Students(String name, int numG,int[] marks){
    this.name = name;
    this.numG = numG;
    this.marks = marks
}
```

Класс с Main:

```
Students [] stud;
stud = new Students[] {
new Students("Бочкарев И.С", 4, new int[]{4, 3, 5, 4, 5});
new Students("Петров И.С", 3, new int[]{4, 3, 5, 4, 5});
new Students("Иванов И.С", 4, new int[]{4, 4, 5, 4, 5});
new Students("Сидоров И.С", 2, new int[]{4, 3, 4, 4, 5});
new Students("Кузнецов И.С", 1, new int[]{4, 3, 5, 4, 5});
new Students("Долгов И.С", 4, new int[]{5, 5, 5, 5, 5});
new Students("Попов И.С", 3, new int[]{4, 4, 4, 4, 3});
new Students("Лопатин И.С", 3, new int[]{4, 5, 3, 4, 5});
new Students("Рубанок И.С", 2, new int[]{4, 3, 4, 4, 5});
new Students("Рубильник И.С", 1, new int[]{2, 3, 3, 4, 5});
}
```

Comment: после this.marks = marks добавьте ;
В методе создания массива студентов замените ; на , (у последнего элемента уберите).

Comment: Да, спасибо, подправил все

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, вам требуется создать массив с объектами типа `Student` (класс которого, уже приведен в вопросе) и осортировать его по возрастанию, где критерием сравнения будет выступать средний балл студента.

Чтобы это сделать вам потребуется реализовать интерфейс `java.lang.Comparable` в классе `Student`. Метод `compareTo` должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public static class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private String name;
    private int numG;
    private int[] marks = new int[5];
    private int averageGrade;

    public Student(String name, int numG, int[] marks) {
        this.name = name;
        this.numG = numG;
        this.marks = marks;

        for (int mark : marks)
            this.averageGrade += mark;

        this.averageGrade /= marks.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.averageGrade, o.averageGrade);
    }
}
```

После чего, можете просто отсортировать массив содержащий данные объекты:

```
Arrays.sort(students)
```

Comment: Не совсем, вопрос скорее был по синтаксической части, а средние баллы и сортировку я сделал) Но все равно спасибо)